# PHP global config files

Tags: php, config, global

i have a config.php file that contains :

```
<?php
// Config File

return array(
    //database connections
    'db_type' = 'mysql';
    'db_host' = 'localhost';
    'db_user' = 'user';
    'db_pass' = 'pass';
    'db_name' = 'name';

);
```

then i call that in my init file (i've tried it with and without the GLOBAL)

```
if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'core' . DS . 'config.php'))
{
    $config = include('config.php');
    GLOBAL $config;
}
```

and in my data base class i've tried using in 2 different ways

1.

```
private $db_type = $config['db_type'];
private $db_host = $config['db_host'];
private $db_user = $config['db_user'];
private $db_pass = $config['db_pass'];
private $db_name = $config['db_name'];
```

2.

```
function __construct() {
    global $config;
    $this->db_type = $config['db_type'];
    $this->db_host = $config['db_host'];
    $this->db_user = $config['db_user'];
    $this->db_pass = $config['db_pass'];
    $this->db_name = $config['db_name'];
}
```

way 1 says unexpected $config, way 2 makes the database throw the error "could not find driver"

my config file won't only contain the database configurate, but things like sitename, root url, common paths etc.

How can I make this work? Is there something I'm missing? Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Does anyone know of a good tutorial or example for this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: (1) Property declarations can't be expressions. (2) You have invalid credentials or are constructing the DSN incorrectly. Why are you assigning the config values to properties anyway? You just need to connect once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global` is evil, please don't use it.

I'd use constants for the database parameters:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'MyDatabase');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '1234');
```

Then, use `require` instead of `include` for your config.php. Your application should not proceed without it.

Comment: Thanks. should I also use define for paths and things like site name that I want to be available globally ?

Comment: That's the way I do it. The advantage here is that the constants make sure that no one will overwrite your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a  '>' character and you should use comma instead of semicolon for separating the key-value pairs:

```
<?php
// Config File

return array(
    //database connections
    'db_type' => 'mysql',
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_user' => 'user',
    'db_pass' => 'pass',
    'db_name' => 'name',

);
```